# Can't uninstall language on ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: 18.04, package-management, dpkg, language-support

I was installed language pack,but now i want to uninstalled it. The problem is i can't uninstalled it the message goes like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove language-pack-id
[sudo] password for marcell: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  language-pack-gnome-id language-pack-gnome-id-base language-pack-id
  language-pack-id-base
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 135 not upgraded.
After this operation, 9,161 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'language-pack-id-base' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

how to fix this?
i'm new user btw Thanks!

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f` then  `sudo apt-get remove language-pack-id`

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall language-pack-id-base`, then try removing again.

Comment: got nothing, the output still remain the same thing

Comment: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'language-pack-id-base' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: sorry for low respon btw